# How to use Windows On-Screen Keyboard in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, 32bit-64bit, on-screen-keyboard

- VS 2010
- Developing 32-bit app that runs on 64-bit OS (Windows 7, Windows 8 - desktop app)
- C#
- .NET 4.0
- WinForms

I have found many threads on launching the Windows on-screen keyboard (`osk.exe`) from an application, but I am running into some problems. It appears to be because I am running a 32-bit app on a 64-bit OS. I've tried the code posted by WooCaSh here: 
[Keyboard on the screen in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298515/keyboard-on-the-screen-in-winforms)

But none of the three different paths work for me. For the `sysnative` path, `Process.Start` fails with  *"Cannot find the path specified."* For the `system32` and `osk.exe` paths, I get the *"Could not start the on-screen keyboard"* error dialog.

I found a possible workaround here, which is a little more complicated than what I was looking for (post by eryang): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/10ebc62f-e6d7-4072-9fd1-ea3784a0966f/

1. Is there an easier or correct way to do this?
2. I was hoping that running my app on a tablet would automatically launch the on-screen keyboard when the user selects a textbox, but no luck. Is this normal or am I missing something? I've found that the keyboard is not automatically launched in Windows 8 when in Desktop mode (which my app is): http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/480250/keyboard-does-not-pop-up-automatically/ Apparently it works on Windows 7 tablets, but I can't test because I only have Windows 8 tablets here.

Comment: Just change the Platform target setting on your EXE project to "AnyCPU".

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be x86 for some 3rd party software it interacts with.

Comment: Just for testing, I went ahead and changed to "AnyCPU". The keyboard still would not launch on my Win7 64-bit desktop, but launches on the Win8 64-bit tablet. Any ideas?

Comment: I've implemented the approach described [here][1]. It works on Win7, too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183720/wpf-windows-8-tabtip-close

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am now launching the "Touch Keyboard" as opposed to the "On-Screen Keyboard" (which is the keyboard I wanted on Windows 8 anyway) with:

```
string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
string keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");

this.keyboardProc = Process.Start(keyboardPath);
```

This works on my Win7 and Win8, regardless of my 32-bit app on 64-bit OS. However, I still have the problem of programmatically closing the keyboard when I'm done. The process, `this.keyboardProc`, does not seem to get the handle, and immediately has property `HasExited = true`. This means my attempts to close or kill it fail.

According to this thread, if the user manually opens the keyboard (or I programmatically launch it), the keyboard will not automatically close/hide when the text field loses focus: [Windows 8 - How to Dismiss Touch Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149006/windows-8-how-to-dismiss-touch-keyboard) I tried the workaround of setting the focus to a hidden button, but since I launched the keyboard myself, it doesn't close automatically.

Comment: Great job! I've wasted at least an hour on this crap. Your solution helped me out.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 tablet as well. Nothing like keeping a dinosaur alive...

Comment: Please note that you might not have the "Tablet PC Components" windows features installed... if not goto the Control Panel, Programs and Turn Windows Features off or on

Comment: It seems that this may now be required on Windows10 for this to work in Desktop Mode: `Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7", "EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke", 1);`

Answer (score 12):

I had trouble closing the on screen keyboard. You can start the Touch Keyboard with

```
string progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
string onScreenKeyboardPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");
onScreenKeyboardProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(onScreenKeyboardPath);
```

and close all keyboards with

```
//Kill all on screen keyboards
Process[] oskProcessArray = Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip");
foreach (Process onscreenProcess in oskProcessArray)
{
    onscreenProcess.Kill();
}
```

For some reason onScreenKeyboardProc.Kill() or .Close() doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

For the keyboard to open up automatically, the controls have to implement some UI Automation control patterns, specifically ITextProvider/IValueProvider. It is a nuisance, but it works (and it is a cleaner way than launching some *.exe)

I wrote a sample app and a short article here: http://blog.tombam.net/implementing-textbox-with-on-screen-touch-keyboard-part-1/

Comment: Fantastic article! Have you discovered a way to force a numeric keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

The touch keyboard leverages the UI automation. For some reasons that are a mystery to me, the standard Windows edit box does not implement UI automation, while other controls, like combo box, do.

---

One can use implementation of UI automation from `UIAutomationClient.dll`.

For the UI automation to be magically injected into an application, class initializer of the assembly internal class `UiaCoreApi` have to be triggered.

On can achieve that for example by calling seeming no-op:

```
AutomationElement.FromHandle(IntPtr)(-1)
```

---

Another way is to implement automation UI explicitly. For that implement the [`ITextProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.provider.itextprovider)/[`IValueProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.provider.ivalueprovider) interfaces for the respective input control.

To bind the implementation of the interfaces to the control, handle [`WM_GETOBJECT` window message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/wm-getobject) with `lParam` = `RootObjectId`.

For an example of implementation, see

- [tombam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15554786/850848#43886052) to this question;
- or directly poster's article [Implementing TextBox with on-screen touch keyboard](https://blog.tombam.net/implementing-textbox-with-on-screen-touch-keyboard-part-1/).

Though interestingly, controls, for which touch keyboard works out-of-the-box (like combo box or password edit box, see the answer), do not implement the `WM_GETOBJECT`/`RootObjectId`. There must be a different machinery behind them.

---

The most common "solution" to this problem, to explicitly popup the keyboard by running the `TabTip.exe` or `osk.exe`, is hardly acceptable.

If for nothing else, then because there's no clean way to hide the keyboard opened by running the `TabTip.exe` (solutions include hacks like killing the process or sending <kbd>Esc</kbd> key).

And actually the above hack does not seem to work anymore in Windows 10 Anniversary Update: [Show touch keyboard (TabTip.exe) in Windows 10 Anniversary edition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38774139/850848).

Answer (score 0):

Starting TabTip.exe no longer works in Widnows 10 Anniversary Edition. I discovered an undocumented COM interface for controlling the touch keyboard. Check the code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921638/332528

Answer (score 0):

I've surfing  here and somewhere else then I implement this:

```
using System.Diagnostics; // remember use this

public partial class Window1 : Window
{

    public Process _p = null;
   
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_p != null)
        {
            _p.Kill();
            _p.Dispose();
            _p = null;
        }
        _p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe");    
    }

    private void Acceso_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_p != null)
        {
            _p.Kill();
            _p.Dispose();
            _p = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It works properly, so I share it here in case it helps as your info helped me.

Comment: Thanks for include the missing lines,  you are right the info already present here  and other web was helpfull  to me, I just collected them in a way that works properly for my case and I hope it can help someone else.

thaks for the feedback.