# Using the Windows On screen keyboard in your Winform application without calling Osk.exe or Tabtip.exe

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to load the windows on-screen keyboard as part of my application (like importing some dlls or something), not with Process.Start(). Just like this article explained - https://blog.tombam.net/implementing-textbox-with-on-screen-touch-keyboard-part-1/ . Only this solution doesn't work for me (the keyboard doesn't pop-up when clicked on the textbox). Is there another way? Or does anybody know what to do with the project that's in the link to make it work?

Thank you for the help in advance :)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554786/how-to-use-windows-on-screen-keyboard-in-c-sharp-winforms) might be of help

Comment: Already checked that one, that's where I found the link given in the description. Thanks for the help anyway